# Ease with/by which -any difference?

Tags: difference

I encountered the sentence

> > Ease by which something may be reached

in this [site](https://www.crosswordgiant.com/crossword-clue/2216330/Ease-by-which-something-may-be-reached). I have heard of and read the expression 'ease with which' many times. However 'ease by which' sounds strange to my ears. [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22ease%20by%20which%22&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&dcr=0&ei=2FHCWaGfBcjlvgTHu4r4Bw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=622) shows that this is not an uncommon usage despite the [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ease%20by%20which%2C%20ease%20with%20which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cease%20by%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cease%20with%20which%3B%2Cc0) results. What I want to know is the difference between the two (if there is any). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caveat: I have no evidence to back this up, other than my own experience of being a "mature" native speaker and an IELTS 9 scorer.

I think "ease by" is an older form that "ease with". That's why you hear the "ease with" more commonly. I've noticed use of English changing in my own lifetime and I now don't hear phrases that I used to hear all the time. "I should like to" changing to "I would like to" etc.